# Virtual Inheritance and dreaded diamond

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

I am having a hard time with a dreaded diamond problem.
For a reminder, here is the classical class hierarchy of this problem:

```
    B
   / \
 C1   C2
   \ /
    D
```

To solve it, the standard solution is to make C1 and C2 use virtual inheritance to inherit from B.

**My problem is that B and C1 are from an SDK that I cannot modify.**
Example below where I cannot make **SubClassB** inherit virtually from **Base**.
Classes: PureVirtualBase, Base and SubClassB are from the SDK I use. I cannot modify them.
SubClassA and Leaf are my custom classes. I can change them.

```
     PureVirtualBase(SDK)
           |
        Base(SDK)
       /        \
 SubClassA   SubClassB(SDK)
       \        /
          Leaf
```

In such a situation where **SubClassB** cannot be changed to use virtual inheritance from **Base**. How what should so that:

- **Leaf** instance only contains one **Base**
- Avoid the ambiguity when trying to access functions defined pure virtual in **PureVirtualBase** and implemented in **Base**

```cpp
class PureVirtualBase
{
public:
    PureVirtualBase()
    {
        cout<<"<<PureVirtualBase::PureVirtualBase" << endl;
        cout<<">>PureVirtualBase::PureVirtualBase" << endl;
    }
    virtual int f_PureVirtualBase()=0;
};
class Base : public PureVirtualBase
{
public:
    Base(std::string id) {
        cout<<"<<Base::Base:"<<id << endl;
        m_id=id;
        cout<<">>Base::Base:"<<m_id << endl;
    }
    virtual int f_PureVirtualBase() {
       cout<<"Base::f_PureVirtualBase" << endl;
       return 1;
    }
private:
    std::string m_id;
};
class SubClassA:  public virtual Base
{
public:
    SubClassA(): Base("From SubClassA") {
        cout<<"<<SubClassA::SubClassA" << endl;
        cout<<">>SubClassA::SubClassA" << endl;
    }
};
class SubClassB:  public Base
{
public:
    SubClassB():Base("From SubClassB") {
        cout<<"<<SubClassB::SubClassB" << endl;
        cout<<">>SubClassB::SubClassB" << endl;
    }
};    
class Leaf:  public SubClassA, public SubClassB
{
public:
    Leaf():SubClassA(),  SubClassB(), Base("From Leaf") {
        cout << "<<Leaf::Leaf" << endl;
        cout << ">>Leaf::Leaf"<< endl;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    Leaf myleaf;
    myleaf.f_PureVirtualBase();
    return a.exec();
}
```

- If I comment the call to f_PurevirtualBase it compiles but I have a
  warning that 
  *virtual base 'Base' inaccessible in 'Leaf' due to ambiguity* If I uncomment this call: I get this error : *request for member
  'f_PureVirtualBase' is ambiguous*
- If I prefix this call by the class name
  (myleaf.SubClassA::f_PureVirtualBase() then it works, but something
  is obviously wrong as there are 2 **Base** contained in the **Leaf**
  Object).

Any hint?

**More info to answer comments**

My target architecture is slightly more complex that the sample I provided in the original question:

```
 PureVirtualBase(SDK)
       |
     Base(SDK)
        |
        --SubClassA
        --SubClassB(SDK)
        --SubClassC(SDK)
        --SubClassD(SDK)
```

LeafOne    : inherits from  SubClassA  and  SubClassB(SDK)

LeafTwo    : inherits from  SubClassA  and  SubClassC(SDK)

LeafThree  : inherits from  SubClassA  and  SubClassD(SDK)

**SubClassA is my own private code. It provides custom functions. It should be able to be treated like a Base instance by SDK methods.**
This class won't be instantiated but it is here to be able to handle LeafOne, LeafTwo and LeafThree in the same when performing some treatment.

Comment: How about one class inherited and another composite.

Comment: It's something i am considering but the integration of such a Leaf Class would not be as elegant in our SDK and lot of different problems will have to be solved. Still you are right, its one way to solve this problem but i would like to find a way to make it though inheritance for easier integration with the SDK features.

Comment: Why do you think that `SubClassA` needs to inherit from `Base` at all? Given the definition of `SubClassB` it is obviously that `Base` is not designed to be a virtual base class in a hierarchy that includes `SubClassB`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Have you thought about templates?

Comment: Because, actually i needto have 3 differents Leafs classes, all of them inheriting from differents subclasses of the SDK (all of them subclasses of "Base").
I edited the original post (at the end for more clarifications).

Comment: @Marc Look at private inheritance, composition. Also, FTFY: "actually **I think** I need to have 3 different leaf classes [...]"

Comment: Learn to *indent* and try to minimize the screen real state when posting to a web forum. That will make the code much easier for others to digest.

Comment: OK, let me ask a different way. What benefit are you trying to achieve by having your "Leaf" classes derive from two sub classes?

Comment: In the end i think you guyz touched the hinted point: I have to make a less elegant solution and use composition. I made some test it seems an ok design for my program.
Thx a lot and I'ill try to write my question in a better format next time.
Marc

Comment: @Marc: Composition is not less elegant than inheritance by any means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indicates a problem with your design, for which the simplest answer is *avoid the diamond* in the first place. Your choice of names for the example code is bad enough to make it hard to reason about what you might actually be wanting to do, but at any rate reconsider whether you *need* to inherit from both parents, and whether that makes sense.

Inheritance is one of the most abused constructs there is in OO languages, it does solve a problem, but it is used as a [golden hammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) everywhere else. Many times what you have in your hand is a [screw](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/30/every-problem-looks-like-a-nail.aspx), not a nail and the correct tool is not a hammer.

Comment: i think you just hit the point. In the end i used your advice and changed our class hierarchy.

Comment: You said this hammer+screw joke also yesterday, isn't it :p ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're really stuck with these design constraints I'd definitely look to subclassing from B directly with an class that took C1 and C2 as composite components.  Unfortunately that requires manually mirroring their interface (hopefully it's small or you can limit it to what you need) and proxying through to the subcomponents.  It's not pretty, but unless you can enforce some give on the design elsewhere, then you're not really left with much choice.

One disadvantage of course is that you don't have the type identity you're looking for (the subclass won't satisfy "isa" of C1 or C2) which may be enough to blow this approach out of the water.

It's not pretty. But I expect that given your constraints it might be the "least bad" solution.