# Data member access ambiguity and diamond inheritance

Tags: c++, c++14, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity, name-lookup

Given the code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    struct A { int i; A(int j) : i(j) { ; } };
    struct E { int i = 3; };
    struct B : A, E { using A::A; };
    struct C : A, E { using A::A; };
    struct D : B, C { D(int i, int j) : B{i}, C{j} { ; } };
    D d{1, 2};
    assert(d.B::A::i == 1);
    assert(d.C::A::i == 2);
    assert(d.B::E::i == 3);
    assert(d.C::E::i == 3);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are two diamond inheritance occurrences. I want to access to specified data members `i` in all bases. How to gain the access? The code from example produces an error:

```
main.cpp:13:12: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'D' to base class 'A':
    struct D -> struct B -> struct A
    struct D -> struct C -> struct A
    assert(d.B::A::i == 1);
           ^
/usr/include/assert.h:92:5: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
  ((expr)                                                               \
    ^
main.cpp:14:12: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'D' to base class 'A':
    struct D -> struct B -> struct A
    struct D -> struct C -> struct A
    assert(d.C::A::i == 2);
           ^
/usr/include/assert.h:92:5: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
  ((expr)                                                               \
    ^
main.cpp:15:12: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'D' to base class 'E':
    struct D -> struct B -> struct E
    struct D -> struct C -> struct E
    assert(d.B::E::i == 3);
           ^
/usr/include/assert.h:92:5: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
  ((expr)                                                               \
    ^
main.cpp:16:12: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'D' to base class 'E':
    struct D -> struct B -> struct E
    struct D -> struct C -> struct E
    assert(d.C::E::i == 3);
           ^
/usr/include/assert.h:92:5: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
  ((expr)                                                               \
    ^
4 errors generated.
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1ba5f8023d05fad)</kbd>

Compiler is *clang 3.7.0*.

Comment: related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027053/virtual-inheritance-and-dreaded-diamond

Comment: `assert(static_cast<B&>(d).A::i == 1);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki What about `E::i`?

Comment: There's the `virtual` keyword, to disambiguate multiply inherited base classes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Roughly speaking, I want `sizeof(D) == 4 * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: `assert(static_cast<B&>(d).E::i == 3);` or `assert(static_cast<C&>(d).E::i == 3);`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It is solution. But why repetitive `::ns` not works?

Comment: @Orient `d.B::A::i` is interpreted by the compiler as access to data member `i` from class `A`, and the class `A` itself (*not* its particular instance) should be searched in scope of class `B`. it doesn't mean "go through my hierarchy to base class `B` and then to *its* base class `A`"

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Indeed!

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Seems it is very hairy theme http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17d0d921fdf08f67 for `clang` contributors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "_There's the virtual keyword, to disambiguate_" no it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a rather messy class hierarchy. I hope you don't intend to use it in a real application.

Here's one way to get around the hurdle:

```
// Get references to the B and C parts of D.
B& b = d;
C& c = d;

// Now you can get the A::i and the E::i.
assert(b.A::i == 1);
assert(c.A::i == 2);
assert(b.E::i == 3);
assert(c.E::i == 3);
```

Comment: Sure, I don't intent to use. It's just a theoretical question.

Comment: Why repetitive namespace resolution operators not works?